# Kubuntu 20.04 mount google drive

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, google-drive

I'm trying to mount my google drive as a local directory (so that it could be used as storage and terminal access). I did add it to the "Online Accounts". I can see the drive in Dolphin. But I can't figure out how to mount it or somehow access from the command line.

All help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As of time of writing, I think you can't mount your google drive locally. The best bet is to use a program like [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse), which allows you to access your locals locally at the same time sync said files **if they weren't created via Google Drive**.

Please note that requires you to use a ppa and use of the terminal.

## Installation

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa`
2. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse`

## Setting your Google Drive Folder

Make sure you have a web browser for this step.

1. `google-drive-ocamlfuse`
2. Follow the prompts that you will get.
3. `mkdir -v ~/myGoogleDrive` this will allow you to create a local copy of your Google Drive folders
4. `google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/myGoogleDrive` this will tell the program to mount the local copy
5. `df -h` to make sure it's mounted or you can `cd` to said folder and `ls` to see the contents

Answer (score 1):

After months struggling with this issue, I searched the Discover Software Center for Google Drive and came across **KIO. KIO seemed to solve the problem - https://community.kde.org/KIO_GDrive**

Once the Google authentication is complete, the files don't start transferring for about a minute or so. Please be aware that there might not be any immediate feedback. After this step, a Google Drive icon will display in the Dolphin File Manager under Remote.